# React component re-render on "change in state or props" or "every state change", confusing official documentation

Tags: reactjs

some more research from my side

( https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate )

here it says

> Use shouldComponentUpdate() to let React know if a component’s output
> is not affected by the current change in state or props. The default
> behavior is to re-render on every state change, and in the vast
> majority of cases you should rely on the default behavior.

Here 1st sentence says `change in state or props` but 2nd sentence says `every state change`, which one is correct ?

or this is documentation bug ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this paragraph, the word 'state' is used in two different meanings. In the first one, it is used as a react-specific component property (as opposed to props). In the second one, it is used with a more generic meaning, like a state of an application.

Components in React re-render if either props or state changed, but you can control it using `shouldComponentUpdate` method by returning false if you want to prevent another re-render.

Comment: I wish documentation uses simplest English possible to avoid this kind of confusion as it's not everyone's native language across globe. Thanks for quick clarification anyways